# Let $a$ and $b$ be integers $\ge 1$. prove that $(2^a-1) | (2^{ab}-1)$.

Tags: number-theory

> Let $a$ and $b$ be integers $\ge 1$. prove the following:
>
> $(2^a-1) | (2^{ab}-1)$

My attempt:

$2^{ab}-1=(2^a)^b-1$

$= (2^a-1)((2^a)^{b-1}+(2^a)^{b-2}+...+2^a+1)$

Since $(2^a)^{b-1}+(2^a)^{b-2}+...+2^a+1\in \Bbb{Z}$,
then

$(2^{ab}-1)\equiv 0 \mod (2^a-1)$.

Is that true, please ?

Comment: See also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265977/prove-that-if-d-divides-n-then-2d-1-divides-2n-1).

Comment: Am I missing something? Your second equals sign makes no sense.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is an exact duplicate, as it asks for a very special case, more friendly to newer students of the material...

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you.

Comment: @TheCount sorry, I edited it.

Comment: @Dima, looks good. The only complaint might be how rigorous it is supposed to be, but it is perfectly clear to me.

Comment: @TheCount Yes, you are right. The second duplicate is better, because it is for $x=2$ more specific, i.e., $2^a-1$ divides $2^d-1$ for $a\mid d$. Now take $d=ab$ here. It is very useful to compare the own proofs with the duplicate ones, I think.

Comment: @TheCount Thank you so much.